# Logging and intercepting database operations when using Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, logging, dependency-injection, .net-core

This link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception shows how to print the generated SQL of EF.

```
using (var context = new BlogContext())
{
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write;

    // Your code here...
}
```

However, in my project (**.Net Core 3.0**), there is no `new ...Context()`. The DbContexts are injected.

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPersistence(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<NorthwindDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("NorthwindDatabase")));

        services.AddScoped<INorthwindDbContext>(provider => provider.GetService<NorthwindDbContext>());

        return services;
    }
}
```

And the following DbContext definition code gets error

```
public class NorthwindDbContext : DbContext, INorthwindDbContext
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    public NorthwindDbContext(DbContextOptions<NorthwindDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
        Database.Log = Console.WriteLine; // Error under "Log"
    }
```

Error:

> Error CS1061  'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'Log' and no accessible extension method 'Log' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  Persistence

Comment: I believe `Database.Log` property is **NOT** defined in EF Core. To log SQL query in .net core, you should follow the approach mentioned in [this](https://wildermuth.com/2018/11/07/EntityFrameworkCore-Logging-in-ASP-NET-Core) link or [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/october/data-points-logging-sql-and-change-tracking-events-in-ef-core) link.

Answer (score 3):

The question is a little bit old, but what you need to do to activate the log of the database operations with Dependency Injection is specifying it on the option when you inject the DbContext, on the startup class:

```
public static class DependencyInjection
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPersistence(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<NorthwindDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(configuration.GetConnectionString("NorthwindDatabase")).LogTo(Console.WriteLine));


        return services;
    }
}
```

After the UseSqlServer you put the LogTo, where you specify where are you going to log the operations.

Comment: For those who wishes to see the SQL output in the Visual Studio debug-window, one can use ".LogTo((x) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(x))"